# $\sigma$-compactness of probability measures under a refined topology

Tags: pr.probability, gn.general-topology, measure-theory, descriptive-set-theory, optimal-transportation

Denote Polish spaces $(X, \tau_x)$ and $(Y, \tau_y)$, where $X$ and $Y$ are closed subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. Consider a Borel measurable function $f: (X \times Y, \tau_x \times \tau_y) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, where $\mathbb{R}$ is equipped with the usual topology.

An application of Theorem 13.11 in the book Classical Descriptive Set Theory by Kechris can prove that, there exists a stronger Polish topology $\tau' \supseteq \tau_x\times\tau_y$ with the same Borel sets $\mathcal{B}(\tau') = \mathcal{B}(\tau_x \times \tau_y)$, such that $f: (X \times Y, \tau') \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous under this stronger topology.

I have a question in my research as follows. Consider two Borel probability measures $\mu \in \mathcal{P}(X)$ and $\nu \in \mathcal{P}(Y)$. Denote $\Pi(\mu, \nu)$ as the set of Borel probability measures $\pi \in \mathcal{P}(X \times Y)$ with marginals $\mu$ and $\nu$.

**My Question**: Can we show $\Pi(\mu, \nu)$ is $\sigma$-compact under the weak topology corresponding to $C_b(X \times Y; \tau')$, that is, continuous and bounded functions under the stronger Polish topology $\tau'$?

**My thoughts**: It's important to note that the refined topology $\tau'$ is not necessarily a product topology. If the original $\tau_x \times \tau_y$ is used, one can apply Prokhorov's theorem to show that $\Pi(\mu, \nu)$ is compact, since $\pi((X \times Y) \backslash (K_x \times K_y)) \leq \mu(X \backslash K_x) + \nu(Y \backslash K_y)$ where $K_x$ is $\tau_x$-compact and $K_y$ is $\tau_y$-compact. $K_x \times K_y$ is compact under the product topology $\tau_x \times \tau_y$.

However, $K_x \times K_y$ may not be compact under $\tau'$. So I relax to show that $\Pi(\mu, \nu)$ is $\sigma$-compact under the weak topology corresponding to $C_b(X \times Y; \tau')$. I'm also okay if we refine $\tau'$ to a stronger Polish topology $\tau''$ which is a product topology, but with same Borel sets. Any reference or guidance on this problem is gratefully appreciated!